# The augmentation filtration on a group ring

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, hopf-algebras, group-rings

Let $G$ be a group and $\mathbb QG=\{\sum a_ig_i\colon a_i\in\mathbb Q, g_i\in G\}$ its group ring over $\mathbb Q$. It is a Hopf algebra. Let $I=\{\sum a_ig_i\colon\sum a_i=0\}$ be the augmentation ideal of $\mathbb QG$. In this case, the algebraic structure of $\mathbb QG$ as a Hopf algebra determines $I$ (meaning, every automorphism of $\mathbb QG$ as a Hopf algebra fixes $I$): Indeed, $I$ is the ideal generated by differences of group-like elements in $\mathbb QG$.

Does the same remain true in $\mathbb QG^{(n)}:={\mathbb Q}G/I^n$ and in $\widehat{\mathbb QG}:=\varprojlim \mathbb QG^{(n)}$? These spaces are again Hopf algebras, and they have natural "augmentation ideals" ($I/I^n$ and $\varprojlim I/I^n$, respectively). Are these augmentation ideals determined by the algebraic structure? If not, is there a large class of groups for which this is easily true?

In an old paper I implied that that was true (*[On Associators and the Grothendieck-Teichmuller Group I](https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9606021)*, remark 2.5), but now I'm no longer sure. If the above is false, I will need to make some minor changes to said paper, but these changes are localized and nothing major changes.

Comment: Isn't $I/I^n $ still the kernel of the counit?

Comment: It is - I should have phrased the question in a more restrictive way - are these augmentation ideals determined by the product and the co-product?

Comment: The counit is uniquely determined by the coproduct; thus, yes.

Comment: Why $\mathbb{Q}G^{(n)}$ are Hopf algebra? Hopf quotients of $\mathbb{C}G^{(n)}$ correspond to group quotients of $G$, (it is consequence of Cartier-Kostant theorem). What are this group quotients?

Comment: Oy, I seem to be getting everything wrong about this matter. ${\mathbb Q}G^{(n)}$ is not a Hopf algebra, though it is probably something like "a Hopf object in the category of filtered vector spaces". That's probably enough for my needs, but I have to go back and confirm, and also confirm that there's no serious issue in the published paper. Later...

As for Cartier-Kostant - I don't know this. Do you have a reference?

Comment: A good reference is http://preprints.ihes.fr/2006/M/M-06-40.pdf see theorem 3.8.2. This theorem has several names, Cartier-Konstant-Milnor-Gabriel. Other good reference is http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-769-topics-in-lie-theory-tensor-categories-spring-2009/lecture-notes/MIT18_769S09_lec07.pdf Theorem 1.33.1.

Comment: I have had to fix the link to the arXiv front, which was broken. Can you please check the new link is to the right paper?